# ProfilesList gone missing in IBM-SBT? Error when trying to deserialise

Tags: xpages, ibm-sbt

I'm using the IBM SBT Java API in Xpages to get a list of profiles and store in viewScope. (sbtsdk-1.0.3.20140723-1200.zip from openntf)
That works fine when the page first opens.

When a partial refresh occurs the following error comes up...

`java.io.InvalidClassException: com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; no valid constructor
com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; no valid constructor`

so some kind of problem when getting it back again.  The odd thing is that if I look at the source code here (sdk\com.ibm.sbt.core\src\main\java\com\ibm\sbt\services\client\connections\profiles)  there's no  ProfilesList java file.
However if I look in the equivalent place in the jar I do see a ProfileList.class file.

So where's the source gone?  I wanted to check to see if it had an explicit serialVersionUID

**EDIT** This works if I change my ServiceBean to convert the ProfileList into an ArrayList instead so there must be something wrong with Serializing ProfileList directly.

NB: Full stack trace..

`com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; no valid constructor
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.restoreView(AbstractStateManager.java:100)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:179)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:386)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:358)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:168)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    org.openntf.domino.xsp.adapter.OpenntfHttpService.doService(OpenntfHttpService.java:89)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileList; no valid constructor
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:791)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1767)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
    java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:957)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1049)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1889)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1793)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUnshared(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectInputStream.readObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:496)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectInputStream.readObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:503)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectInputStream.readObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:482)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectInputStream.readObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:503)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectInputStream.readObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:503)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.readSerializedView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:215)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.doRestoreView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:127)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doRestoreView(FileStateManager.java:249)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.restoreView(AbstractStateManager.java:93)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:179)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:386)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:358)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:168)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    org.openntf.domino.xsp.adapter.OpenntfHttpService.doService(OpenntfHttpService.java:89)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)`

Comment: maybe check to see if you have older plugins in the system? maybe they are in conflict?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that these classes have been removed in version 1.1.0, which causes some issues in XPages.

See issue in github here
https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/issues/1638